# python json object parsing

Tags: python, json, object

How to parse python json object?

Currently i'm getting this value from another json file, it is a variable "Id6087b9b5b5"
But what if i don't know the object string but i want to fetch "_number" in a loop?

try.py

```
for sub_dict in y[ChangeID]:  #ChangeID is a variable
    print (ChangeID)
    MERGENUM = (entry['_number'])
    print (MERGENUM
```

)

data.json

```
  {
      "Id6087b9b5b5": [
        {
          "status": "NEW",
          "_number": 35328
        }
      ],
      "Id6087b9b345": [
        {
          "status": "NEW",
          "_number": 35348
        }
      ],
      "Id6087b9b555": [
        {
          "status": "NEW",
          "_number": 35310
        }
      ],
      "Id6087b9b5b4": [
        {
          "status": "NEW",
          "_number": 35308
        }
      ]
    }
```

**output as a variable**

```
35328
35348
35310
35308
```

Comment: What is `entry`?

Comment: I'm trying to fetch data of "_number"

Comment: I understand that, but `entry` is not defined in your code.

Comment: should entry - > sub_dict? if not then something is missing from your post

Comment: yeah, that is correct... replacing entry with sub_dict works.. i made a mistake.. But what if i don't know the object string "Id6087b9b5b4", how can i still get the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `json` parse the json string to object and then iterate the object with for loop (in this way, you don't need to know the IDs) and get the inner object, each inner object is an array which use inner_object[0] to get the first object:

```
import json
data = '''{
      "Id6087b9b5b5": [
        {
          "status": "NEW",
          "_number": 35328
        }
      ],
      "Id6087b9b345": [
        {
          "status": "NEW",
          "_number": 35348
        }
      ],
      "Id6087b9b555": [
        {
          "status": "NEW",
          "_number": 35310
        }
      ],
      "Id6087b9b5b4": [
        {
          "status": "NEW",
          "_number": 35308
        }
      ]
    }'''

print(data)

obj = json.loads(data)

for nid in obj:
    inner_obj = obj[nid][0]
    num = inner_obj['_number']
    print(num)
```

Comment: Thank you this is what i was looking for.. same logic can be applied if the data is a text file, correct?

Comment: @Mihir no, not unless that text file happened to contain a valid json object

Comment: By text file, i meant data.json file.

Comment: @Mihir then you would want to open the file and use `json.load()` (note the lack of `s` at the end, which signifies "string")